# DUMMY Column to the VIEW

Tags: sql, plsql, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view containing a column named COMPONENT. And that column allows SPACES. Am using this VIEW to populate the data on the report.

So, I have crystal formula to get the details. When the formula is triggered for the COMPONENT records that has the SPACES, its failing to launch the report and application gets crashed.

So, my question is. Can we add a DUMMY column to the VIEW and populate the same details of the COMPONENT with modified values by replacing the SPACES with UNDERSCORE?

Example: 
"Average Result" to be displayed like "Average_Result"in the DUMMY column
and 
"Loss on Drying" to be displayed like "Loss_on_Drying" in the DUMMY column

Can we get this sort of DUMMY column added to my VIEW?

Comment: Post your view query so that we can see how you are creating your view.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace()` function e.g.

```
select REPLACE('Average Result', ' ', '_') from dual;
Result: 'Average_Result'
```

or, for the component column:

```
select ..., REPLACE(COMPONENT, ' ', '_') as component ...
```

Comment: When I using this in my VIEW's query, its giving me an error as INVALID IDENTIFIER in GROUP BY CLAUSE.
They query is lengthy, can you please share the email ID so that I can share over email. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Add dummy column to your select params and replace your required chars,

```
select REPLACE(COMPONENT, ' ', '_') as COMPONENT from TableName
```

Comment: When I using this in my VIEW's query, its giving me an error as INVALID IDENTIFIER in GROUP BY CLAUSE.

Comment: When I using this in my VIEW's query, its giving me an error as INVALID IDENTIFIER in GROUP BY CLAUSE.
They query is lengthy, can you please share the email ID so that I can share over email.

Comment: add REPLACE(COMPONENT, ' ', '_') to your group by clause ?